# Why we use the singular form when we talk generally about "lifestyle"?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

Both examples are extracted from The Guardian newspaper.

> Clark points out that Coca-Cola is at least promoting its Coca-Cola
>   Zero at the Rugby World Cup later this year rather than its full sugar
>   Coca-Cola as it did with its London Olympics sponsorship, but stresses
>   that **a healthy lifestyle** “**is** about what goes into your body
>   and the effects that can have, not just running around a bit to burn
>   off a few calories”.

If I wrote the above paragraph, I would write "healthy lifestyle**s**" **are** bla bla bla. This is because the paragraph is generally talking about "lifestyle" which is a countable noun. The following example was extracted as well from the Guardian:

> Other initiatives include equal attention to mental and physical
>   health and partnering with day-care facilities, schools, workplaces
>   and others to embed *healthy lifestyle**s***.

**What I missed here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that "lifestyle" is a countable noun.   And the way you would write the sentence, "healthy lifestyle**s are** bla bla bla," would be fine also.

Information that is true in general for healthy lifestyles can be attributed to all lifestyle**s** (plural) or to a random instance of **a** lifestyle. If it's true for all,it's true for each.

This is true for most countable nouns:

> "Horses can be temperamental." = "A horse can be temperamental."
>
> "Don't take prescription drugs that were meant for someone else." =
>   "Don't take a prescription drug that was meant for someone else."
>
> "You can buy textbooks in the bookstore." = "You can buy a textbook in
>   the bookstore."